# element.remove() method doesn't work sometimes

Tags: angularjs

I have a test case that shows that angular `element.remove()` removes elements from the DOM sometimes, and fails miserably at other times even though I don't see an error. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/marvin_the_paranoid/9ep0cesj/).

To see it working, click the `Search` button (no need to put in any data in the input field). This does two things:

1. deletes elements above the field and
2. deletes any elements below the fields (nothing to delete the first time around) and adds new ones.

This is the code that should clear out the elements below the search button.

```
$scope.searchTargets.forEach(function(target){
    var resultNode = angular.element(document.getElementById('id_' + target.name));
    if(resultNode != undefined)
        resultNode.remove();
```

Repeatedly clicking on the search shows that the number of elements below the search button keeps increasing - even though it should really be staying at 3 elements. Why does the `remove()` method fail here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this forked fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wcca93qc/

You need to reset the search results during each search using `$scope.searchResults = [];`

I also refactored to code a bit, to merge 3 loops that basically can be done in 1 loop.